# Telling unique values in a short array

Tags: algorithms, sorting, efficiency

I have thousands of short arrays (length less than 9) holding integers. These numbers can be identical with high probability (in many arrays there are two triples of equal numbers). I need to remove the duplicates in each array, as efficiently as possible.

An obvious solution is to sort using a fast sort (such as straight selection), then to compress with a linear pass. But is there a smarter way ?

Worth to know: the identical values are often consecutive (but not always). In-place processing is preferred.

Comment: Is there a range/constrain in which the integer elements in each array belong to?

Comment: @ArunMadhav: no, they can span the whole 32 bits range.

Comment: Doing what you described will take around $10^{-5}-10^{-4}$ seconds. Is it a problem?

Comment: @Dmitry: yes, my time scale is milliseconds total time. So optimizations matter.

Comment: Then the fastest approach is probably to just write the relevant parts in assembler.

Comment: @Dmitry: I trust that the compiler will generate better assembly than myself. But the algorithm should be good.

Comment: You might reconsider this belief (although I'm not sure myself). Things might have changed, but while a compiler is definitely better in optimizing large programs, optimizing a small piece of code can be done much better manually. (As I recall from many years ago) instead of Fourier transform it was possible to write $O(n^2)$ algorithm in assembler, and it passed the time limit for $n = 10^5$.

Comment: @Dmitry: compilers are very good at register allocation and instruction reordering. They know their processor much better than me. Even though we are talking of tiny $n$, I prefer to address the $O$ complexity before the hidden constant. Thank you anyway for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

After posting my question, I realized that it contains the answer. As there can be many duplicates, the size of the compressed array tends to be quite short. So

- it is advisable to avoid eliminating the duplicates as soon as possible. A modified straight insertion sort could do, the modification consisting of just dropping an element when it is found to be a duplicate,
- there is little benefit in keeping the values sorted. (The cost of keeping sorted order is that one might have to shift elements many times.)

Hence I will try this solution:

- consider every element in turn,
- search backward among the elements previously considered and kept,
- if the same value is found, drop the element; otherwise append it to those that were kept.

This is easily implemented in-place.